# Pycharm does not find GAE installation

Tags: google-app-engine, pycharm

When I create a new Google App Engine project with PyCharm, the `App Engine SDK Directory` field is automatically filled with the correct value.

The path name is the same used to run the app and the app runs without problems, but the `Create` button is grayed out and the message `Please select App Engine SDK directory` does not go away.

The folder is `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin`.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. In case you haven't already used the Cloud SDK to deploy or run the local development server, install the App Engine Python component of the SDK manually:

   ```
   gcloud components install app-engine-python
   ```
2. Change your App Engine SDK path in PyCharm to:

   ```
   C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\app_engine\
   ```

Comment: I didn't need the first step. The correct folder is `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine`. Now it works as expected.

Comment: I had to change the SDK path in the general settings (wait for a background index task to complete), the New Project, accepted 
    C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\app_engine\

Answer (score 2):

When installing google Cloud SDK, the appengine is not being installed automatically. So you have to install it before first use of google Cloud SDK.

If you install google cloud SDK **for current user** google_appengine path is

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\
```

If you install google cloud SDK **for all users** the google_appengine path is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform
```